# Having trouble trying to find a simple probability for a hazard-rate function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose that the life distribution of an item has hazard rate function $λ(t)=3.9t^{2}, t>0.$ What is the probability that  the item doesn't survive to age 1?

Would I just integrate the function from 0 to 1 and subtract the answer from 1? I am trying to do this and the computer says it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that hazard is density divided by survival:  $$\lambda(t) = \frac{f_T(t)}{S_T(t)},$$ where $T$ is the lifetime random variable.  We also recall that $$S_T(t) = \Pr[T > t] = 1 - \Pr[T \le t] = 1 - F_T(t),$$ as well as $$f_T(t) = F'_T(t).$$  Thus $$f_T(t) = -S'_T(t),$$ and $$\lambda(t) = - \frac{S'_T(t)}{S_T(t)} = - \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \log S_T(t) \right].$$  Consequently, $$S_T(t) = \exp\left( - \int_{u=0}^t \lambda(u) \, du \right).$$  From here, it is straightforward to compute $$\Pr[T < 1] = 1 - S_T(1) = 1 - \exp\left( - \int_{u=0}^1 3.9u^2 \, du \right).$$